# Como saber se um arquivo existe no Storage Firabase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou usando o Storage do Firebase para armazenar foto de perfil do usuário, fiz um método para buscar a imagem e colocar numa ImageView. Funciona muito bem quando a imagem existe no Firebase, mas quando não existe, deixa o ImageView sem nada, não aparece nem a imagem padrão que coloquei no XML. Como faço pra tratar quando o método não retornar uma imagem?

```
private void buscarFotoPerfil(String idUsuario) {

    try {
        storage = ConexaoFirebase.getStorageReference()
                .child("images/perfil/" + idUsuario + ".jpg");

        Glide.with(this)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(storage)
                .into(imagePerfil);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao carregar foto do perfil." + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a método `placeholder()` enquanto carrega a imagem e o método `error()` caso ocorrer algum erro no carregamento da imagem. Veja:

**[Glide 4.x](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html)**:

```
GlideApp.with(this)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
    .load(storage)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
    .error(R.drawable.image_error)
    .into(imagePerfil);
```

**Glide 3.x**:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
    .load(storage)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
    .error(R.drawable.image_error)
    .into(imagePerfil);
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema 100%, valeu mesmo!

Comment: @Henriqueedu se a resposta ajudou resolver seu problema, se quiser pode valida-la. Se houver mais alguma dúvida, estou por aqui.